# Not using referral exclusions in Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, multiple-domains, top-level-domains, referrer, universal-analytics

I have the following website setup:

One property called `example.com`.

On this property, I track multiple domains and subdomains, such as:

- `www.example.dk`
- `subdomain.example.dk`
- `www.example.se`
- `www.example.de`
- `www.example.es`
- ...

I am currently using old Analytics (not universal) but have started the process for migration. Have not yet updated the tracking code.

**What will happen if I don't add the domains to the Referral Exclusion List?** Will then every pageview, let's say on `www.example.dk`, be treated as a session, because it's coming from a referral (`www.example.dk`) not on the list of excluded referrals?

The reason I don't want to add the domains to the Referral Exclusion list is because I want to still be able to track cross-domain referrals (like from `www.example.dk` to `www.example.de` for example), and also managing the list manually with each new domain is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Hi, sorry for posting a too broad question. I was re-posting this from the Google Analytics product forum, where nobody answered yet. It should be now more clear what I'm asking. If not, let me know.

Comment: OK, thanks for narrowing it down. If you do end up getting a suitable answer there but not here, please add it below in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This is from: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en. In particular, to answer your question, I've bolded a specific sentence.

> How excluding referral traffic affects your data
>
> **By default, a referral automatically triggers a new session**. When you
> exclude a referral source, traffic that arrives to your site from the
> excluded domain doesn’t trigger a new session. If you want traffic
> arriving from a specific site to trigger a new session, don't include
> that domain in this table.
>
> Because each referral triggers a new session, excluding referrals (or
> not excluding referrals) affects how sessions are calculated in your
> account. The same interaction can be counted as either one or two
> sessions, based on how you treat referrals. For example, a user on
> my-site.com goes to your-site.com, and then returns to my-site.com. If
> you do not exclude your-site.com as a referring domain, two sessions
> are counted, one for each arrival at my-site.com. If, however, you
> exclude referrals from your-site.com, the second arrival to
> my-site.com does not trigger a new session, and only one session is
> counted.

Comment: I have read this sentence myself when I was researching, it's pretty clear about distinguishing traffic between 2 different domains, but it doesn't say anything about the traffic from the same domain, for example from www.mycompany.dk/front_page to www.mycompany.dk/other_page - would that count as 2 sessions? A referral is technically also set when it's the same domain.

Comment: OK, in that case it shouldn't register as a new session is from within the same domain; the cookie would have already been set for that particular domain, which would preclude a new session from starting.

Comment: If you are quite certain that is the case, then you can modify your answer to include that information and I can accept your answer. Thanks!